# Send Notification to Multiple FCM Tokens

Tags: swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, nsjsonserialization

I have a class (`PushNotificationSender`). This class holds one function called `sendPushNotification` which takes in an `FCM Token`, `Notification title`, and `Notification body`. I have used it to successfully send a notification to one user, given that I know their `FCM Token`.

My goal: to use this function to send the same notification to multiple users.

I have tried to call it for every user's `FCM Token` and I have also tried to change the function's parameters to get an array of tokens, rather than just one, but nothing has worked yet. Any ideas on how to accomplish upgrade?

`PushNotificationSender`:

```
class PushNotificationSender {

    init() {}

    // MARK: Public Functions

    public func sendPushNotification(to token: String, title: String, body: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let paramString: [String : Any] = ["to" : token,
                                           "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body],
                                           "data" : ["user" : "test_id"]
        ]

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue(//key, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let jsonData = data {
                    if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                    }
                }
            } catch let err as NSError {
                print(err.debugDescription)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        completion()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

To send to multiple tokens you should get them into `registration_ids`.
Full documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

**And PLEASE, don't share your private keys in your code. Is not safe.**

Full code:

```
class PushNotificationSender {

init() {}

// MARK: Public Functions

public func sendPushNotification(to token: String, title: String, body: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let paramString: [String : Any] = ["registration_ids" : ["<token1>", "<token2>", "<token3>"],
                                       "notification" : ["title" : title, "body" : body],
                                       "data" : ["user" : "test_id"]
    ]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("your key", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            if let jsonData = data {
                if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                }
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    completion()
}
```

}

Comment: I like how you told not to share keys in code but included the key in the answers code. Though, yes, that key is now compromised anyway..

Comment: If I'm using this request, can users get the push notifications when app is killed too?